# Identify your date falls between set of date range

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I have input parameter MMDD-MMDD and i have one date value example 10th Nov so now I need to check whether 10th Nov falls between MMDD-MMDD.

Currently I have a code which is working fine if the format is like this 0122-1123 but not working for 1123-0122.

So I have done one solution but its not working. When the date range is flipped(1123-0122), i will add year to both and add plus year to 0122, so it becomes nov-23-2019 to jan-22-2020 but I selected one date (jan 21-2019) then obviously it didnt get selected, could you please help me with the logic to identify whether given date falls in between the range or not without using 
year.

```
Date procDate = getProcessDateTime().getDate();
String dateRanges=getDateRange().trim();
int leftSetMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateRanges.substring(0, 2));
int leftSetDate = Integer.parseInt(dateRanges.substring(2, 4));
int rightSetMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateRanges.substring(5, 7));
int rightSetDate = Integer.parseInt(dateRanges.substring(7, 9));

Date leftCollectiveDate = new Date(procDate.getYear(), leftSetMonth, leftSetDate);

Date rightCollectiveDate = new Date(procDate.getYear(), rightSetMonth, rightSetDate);

if (leftCollectiveDate.isAfter(rightCollectiveDate)) {
    rightCollectiveDate = new Date(procDate.getYear() + 1, rightSetMonth, rightSetDate);
}

if (leftCollectiveDate.isSameOrBefore(procDate) && rightCollectiveDate.isSameOrAfter(procDate)) {
    result = Bool.TRUE;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you want help, you should post some code.

Comment: I did,  please check

Comment: **Please** read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and then edit your question. We want to help you; but you have to help us help you.

Comment: We can't help unless we understand the rules you want to apply.  The rules that you have laid out in the post are that jan 21-2019 should not be selected given the range 1123-0122.  If you are saying that that's wrong (ie. you want jan 21-2019 to be selected ), then please explain the rule that allows that.

Comment: You could split the validation in two, between "from" to 12-31 and between 01-01 to "to" when "from" is after "to"

Comment: HI @JoakimDanielson could you please explain it in detail with pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using LocalDate (using the variables declared in the question)

```
LocalDate localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(procDate.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear(), leftSetMonth, leftSetDate);
LocalDate toDate = LocalDate.of(localDate.getYear(), rightSetMonth, rightSetDate);

if (toDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
  toDate = toDate.plusYears(1);
}

if (localDate.isAfter(from) && localDate.isBefore(to)) {
  System.out.println(localDate + " is valid");
} else {
  System.out.println("Out of range");
}
```